# What is the difference between the encodings for the call instruction in x86 asm?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

For reference: an HTML extract of Intel's documentation for the [`call` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html).

---

I am aware that section 3.1.1.3 explains this but I am having trouble understanding the manual, probably because it is too technical.

1. What is the `/2` and `/3` inside `FF /2` and `FF /3`?
2. What is the difference between `r/m32` and `m16:32`? `r/m32` covers both 32-bit registers and memory operands so wouldn't that make `m16:32` redundant?
3. According to the manual `call ptr16:32` is a "Call far, absolute, address given in operand". If I understood correctly, this will allow me to call a function at a given absolute 32-bit address. How can I call the function at the absolute address `0x717A60` (I'm using the inline assembler in MSVC)? `call 0x717A60` gives me an error and `call ds:0x717A60` is assembled to `call [0x717A60]`.
4. Which opcode does the following machine code correspond to? `FF 15 90 98 76 70`

Comment: @rcgldr: It doesn't *use* a segment register, it's a `far call` that loads `CS`.  You don't want that.

Comment: How is C++ involved in this?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: There's a question about generating a `call` to an absolute address using msvc inline asm buried as part of item 3.  I didn't notice that until I was mostly done writing an answer to the obvious parts of the question.  This is a great example of why SO has a one question per Question-post guideline.

Comment: Near duplicate of [x86 function call types](//stackoverflow.com/q/20264452), but I'm not sure which if either should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: the first part is a duplicate of [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24295464/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `/2` vs. `/3`: See *Section 3.1.1.1O Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table*:

> /digit — A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction uses only the r/m (register
> or memory) operand. The reg field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode.

Using the `/r` field of the mod/rm byte of one-operand instructions is the same here as for instructions like `inc r/m32` (`FF /0`).

x86 overloads a few opcode bytes with multiple one-operand instructions this way.  The 3-bit `/r` field becomes another 3 opcode bits instead of an operand.  More detail about that:

- [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236)
- [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295464/what-does-the-4-mean-in-ff-4)
- [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511482/x64-instruction-encoding-and-the-modrm-byte) - details about the fields in the modrm byte.

---

#### `r/m32` vs. `m16:32` vs. `ptr16:32`

See also [x86 function call types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264452/x86-function-call-types)

A "far" `call` loads the `CS` segment register as well as `IP`/`EIP`/`RIP`.  A normal "near" call only needs a 32-bit (or 64-bit) address, and doesn't modify `CS`.

`far call` is never used in "normal" 32 or 64-bit user-space code on normal OSes, because they all use a flat memory model.

`ptr16:32` is an immediate, with the 16-bit segment value and the 32-bit absolute address encoded into the instruction (little-endian, with the 32-bit offset first then the new CS value).  **This is a `far call`**.  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545093/can-someone-explain-this-directly-assembled-x86-jmp-opcode).  Assemblers will generate this instruction encoding for `far call some_symbol`, taking the segment value from the segment `some_symbol` is defined in.  Again, you're really unlikely to ever use this outside of 16-bit code.  But if you do, see [this Q&A for how to get MASM to emit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706833/how-to-code-a-far-absolute-jmp-call-instruction-in-masm).

`m16:32` is a 6-byte memory operand, loaded from the effective address encoded by the ModR/M byte.  **This is another far call**.  So `call far [eax]` does a 48-bit load from the address in `eax`.  Only memory addressing modes are legal for the ModR/M byte, because the instruction needs more data than the width of a register.  (i.e. `call far eax` isn't legal)

**`r/m32`** is a memory or register operand **for a near call.**  You get this from `call eax` or `call [eax]`.  Of course any addressing mode is legal, e.g. `call FS:[edi + esi*4 + some_table]`.  The FS segment-override prefix applies to the location the function pointer is loaded from, not the segment that it jumps to.  (i.e. it doesn't change CS because it's still a near call.)

---

> How can I call the function at the absolute address 0x717A60

See [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code).

If your code doesn't have to be position-independent, by far the best choice is something that assembles to `call rel32` with the right relative displacement to reach that address.  In NASM and AT&T syntax, you can simply write `call 0x717A60` and the assembler + linker take care of it.  I'm not sure how to write it in MASM;  MSVC inline asm doesn't accept `call 123456h`.

There is no absolute direct near `call` encoding, so if you do need PIC then you should do something like `mov eax, 0x717A60` / `call eax`.

You don't want to use a `call far` absolute direct call, because it's probably *much* slower, and pushes CS:EIP instead of just EIP as the return address.  You'd also have to know what to put in the segment field.

---

> `FF 15 90 98 76 70`

That disassembles to `call   DWORD PTR ds:0x70769890` (in GNU `objdump -Mintel` syntax), which is a `call r/m32`, where the operand is a `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode.

(Or in 64-bit code, it's a RIP-relative addressing mode with that `rel32`, but still a memory-indirect `call` that loads a function-pointer from a static location.)

---

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links to docs.